# Connecting to an mdb on a local server through android device using Ucanaccess

Tags: android, database, android-studio, ucanaccess

Hi All who are interested.

I've taken it upon myself to work on a small project (with big ideas..!) for work which I think will massively improve productivity. It's also challenging me to learn some new - app developing for Android devices!

I've identified as Ucanaccess as the starter for connecting to the database from the Android device.

I just need a pointer in determining what should be my connection URL (jdbc:ucanaccess://). From what I've read up on, typically you would map the folder i.e. X:\ and you're on your way basically.

My Android device is on a local network, my database is on the same network, in a shared folder of a regular desktop PC.

Ideally I'd like to keep password protection on the folder containing the database as it, allowing only users with login credentials on the PC.

If I was to put the database on the Android device for testing purposes of other functions, for example SDCard\Documents. What would the URL need to be then for Ucanaccess to work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your ultimate goal is to have multiple concurrent users running the Android app and updating a shared database then UCanAccess is not a good fit. See the UCanAccess blog post

[Multiuser concurrent write access](http://ucanaccess.blogspot.ca/2017/07/multiuser-concurrent-write-access.html)

for details.

Comment: Thanks, a key point to consider. Does jdbc support concurrent sessions on SQL Server?

It looks like I shouldn't spend so much time on the Ucanaccess side of things then but I think I would like to demonstrate the concept to justify the expense for SQL Server should it be needed. Is it possible to connect from the Android device to a shared database on a network PC after all? What should the string be?